# Laravel / Livewire input returning blank when using eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire-3

using laravel livewire for a form, the form submits ok and if i enter details manually this works fine. However if i use an input it just returns null?

So for example.

`$absence = Absence::create(['reason' =>  $this->reason_add]);`

returns null in database or via dd();

`$absence = Absence::create(['reason' =>  'test']);`

returns test in database as expected.

if run

`dd($this->reason_add);`

This returns the value as expected

i dont understand why soon as i add this to Absence::create the input returns null ?

Am i missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added `wire:model="reason_add"` correctly and the database field is fillable in the `Absence` model

Answer (score -1):

when you running `dd($this->reason_add);` and it returns the value as expected i think `wire:model='reason_add'` pass correctly data to the function.So maybe problem in your model and check it.

Comment: Thanks ill try again, i did add these so not sure why its not working.